# Final render looks dim and colorless

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm not too experienced in fine tuning renders..
I've got this scene that's set in a night time fancy resturant-type place. I want to have it set up so that the lights are very bright- almost blinding brightness. [image]

I'm not quite sure what to do. My guess is I need to do some post-processing magic or something. I want the interior of the building to be very bright, vibrant, and colorful. The only post-processing I've added is a bit of blur. [image]

[Project files are here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzgDIjhDOu6ETkdoRHRBUHNOSU0?usp=sharing)
*All textures used in this are freely available, so there's no issues with you downloading this.*

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the trick. The main reason for the lack of light is the *lack of lights*... I added in another type of lamp on the roof that is much bigger, turned down the bloom I was using a lot... and tweak some color settings and *viola*
[image]